# Perl: How capture the outputs of Expect.pm?

Tags: perl, glob

I wrote a piece of perl code to generating ssh keys using Expect.pm. The code can create keys as expected. But I don't know how to capture the **finger prints** from the output.

```
use Expect;

my $passwd = "abcdefg";
my $keyFile = './mykey';
my $cmd = qq/ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "my comments" -f $keyFile/;
print "\nCMD: $cmd\n\n";
my @output;
my $session=Expect->spawn($cmd) or die "Error calling external program:  $!\n";
unless ($session->expect(5,"Enter passphrase \(empty for no passphrase\): ")) {};
print $session "$passwd\r";
unless (@output = $session->expect(5,"Enter same passphrase again: ")) {}; # Capture the output
print $session "$passwd\r";
$session->soft_close();
my $i = 1;
foreach my $e (@output) {
    if($e) {
        print "\$i = $i, Type of \$e: #". ref($e) . "#, Value of \$e: #$e#\n";
    }
    else {
        print "$i, NULL Element!\n";
    }
    $i++;
}
exit;
```

Below is the output:

```
% ./test.pl

CMD: ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "my comments" -f ./mykey
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase):
Enter same passphrase again:
Your identification has been saved in ./mykey.
Your public key has been saved in ./mykey.pub.
**The key fingerprint is:
df:aa:35:19:28:06:0e:97:ec:6d:83:26:b9:01:4f:50** my comments
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ RSA 2048]----+
|..E              |
| . . .           |
|. o =            |
| + * +   .       |
|  = = * S .      |
|   = o o . +     |
|  .       = .    |
|         . o     |
|        ...      |
+-----------------+
$i = 1, Type of $e: ##, Value of $e: #1#
2, NULL Element!
$i = 3, Type of $e: ##, Value of $e: #Enter same passphrase again: #
$i = 4, Type of $e: ##, Value of $e: #
#
5, NULL Element!
$i = 6, Type of $e: #Expect#, Value of $e: #Expect=GLOB(0x1e74b38)#
```

I guess the info is in the Glob? But how to parse the Glob?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I don't know an answer to your glob question. However, is the @output array easier to comprehend under Data::Dumper? (eg Add the module...) use Data::Dumper; (Then print the output of Dumper...) print Dumper(\@output), "\n";

Comment: To @crw, thanks for the inputs. I tried using Dumper and here is the output:`$VAR1 = [
          1,
          undef,
          'Enter same passphrase again: ',
          '
',
          '',
          bless( \*Symbol::GEN0, 'Expect' )
        ];
`

Answer (score 3):

This following should work or at least you should be able to modify it to suite you needs.
I'm waiting for the string "my comment" which is printed after fingerprint and then read the fingerprint using *exp_before* method.

```
use strict;
use Expect;

my $passwd = "abcdefg";
my $keyFile = './mykey';

my $cmd = qq/ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 2048 -C "my comments" -f $keyFile/;

my $session=Expect->spawn($cmd) or die "Error calling external program:  $!";    

my $output;        
$session->expect(10,
  [ qr/passphrase/i, sub { my $self = shift;
      $self->send("$passwd\n");
      exp_continue; }],
  [ qr/my comments/i, sub { my $self = shift;
      $output = $self->exp_before;
      exp_continue; }],
);


      print $output;

$session->soft_close;
```